# How fast do controlled parameters follow the controlling ones?

Tags: abstract-algebra, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the **two** roots (blue) of $f(z) = z^2 - e^{i\varphi}$ that "follow" $\varphi$ (black) with **half** speed (from [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892096/visualizing-and-understanding-the-roots-of-fz-z2-ei-varphi)):

[image]

Are there comparable statements of a similar kind: About the total or average "speed" of some "controlled" parameters in relation to the speed of some "controlling" parameters?

I know this is a very general and somehow vague question, but maybe someone bites.

Comment: You mean something more general like the roots of $z^n-e^{i\,\phi}$ (which move $n$ times as slow)?

Comment: Yes, I mean something more general.

Comment: For general $n$ and function $f(z)=z^{n}-e^{i\varphi}$ there are exactly $n$ roots whcih are all located on the unit circle and have the general form $z_j=e^{i\varphi_j}$ with $\varphi_j=\frac{2j\pi}{n}+\frac{\varphi}{n}$ ($j=0,1,\cdots,n-1$). Obviously, $\frac{d\varphi_j}{d\varphi}=\frac{1}{n}$ i.e. all roots move along the unit circle with velocity $1/n$ as $\varphi$ varies.